# Setting 'EDITOR' or 'BUNDLER_EDITOR' environment variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line, environment-variables, bundler

I am trying to open up a gem in Sublime Text, unsuccessfully.  I have Bundler installed.  Here is what is happening.

In the command line:

```
$bundle open Devise
To open a bundled gem, set $EDITOR or $BUNDLER_EDITOR
```

When I go to the [Bundler website](http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundle_open.html) it says,

> Open the source directory of the given bundled gem:
>
> $ bundle open GEM
>
> This opens the source directory of the provided GEM in your editor. **For this to work the `EDITOR` or `BUNDLER_EDITOR` environment variable has to be set.**

I am new to all of this.  What are the **specific** steps to set my `EDITOR` or `BUNDLER_EDITOR` environment variables?  I'm on a Mac, using Sublime Text.

Thank you.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Assuming you're using the bash shell, you'll want to edit either your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` with:

```
export EDITOR=<editor name>
```

Example, specifically for Sublime:

```
export EDITOR='subl -w'
```

See: [Sublime OS X Command Line docs](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html)

Comment: For my version of Sublime Text 2, I had to use `export EDITOR='sublime -w'`

Comment: I got an error when using the `-w` flag. Worked fine for me without it (Sublime 2)

Comment: If you want to open it in TextMate, run `which mate` and then use that value for the `EDITOR` variable.

Comment: The instructions there require setting up a `~/bin` folder and `subl` link, which I was too lazy to do. This works out-of-the-box: `export EDITOR='"/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" -w'`

Comment: For VSCode you can do: `export EDITOR='code --wait'`

Answer (score 12):

As @sixty4bit mentioned,

```
export EDITOR='subl -w'
```

will raise error for command `bundle open gem_name`

But if I use

```
export EDITOR='subl'
```

Then sublime will not write commit message to git commit correctly for command `git commit`.

So I think it is better to use this config:

```
export EDITOR="subl -w"
export BUNDLER_EDITOR="subl"
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of adding a Visual Studio Code editor:

```
export EDITOR="code"
```